# What abstraction exactly is a "tree traversal" combining nodes to the root?

Tags: haskell, tree

[`Data.Tree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) has a `Tree a` data type which is basically as:

```
Tree a = Tree a [Tree a]
```

(not exactly but that's the basic idea)

This structure (almost) looks very nice for a filesystem style tree.

Lets say I've got this structure, and I want to make a function of type:

```
f :: Tree a -> [a]
```

Which basically does the following:

```
f (Tree "a" [Tree "b" [], Tree "c" [Tree "d" []]] 
  == ["a", "ab", "ac", "acd"]
```

now I'm not asking how to code this up, indeed it's fairly trivial to do. But the data type `Tree` is an instance of `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Monad`, etc.

Could I implement `f` in terms of folds, maps, etc? Or is there some other abstraction that `f` is similar too? I'm happy for you to assume that `a` is a `Monoid` if that helps.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monoid+a+%3D%3E+t+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D

Comment: flatten is `Data.Foldable.toList`

Comment: Data.Tree.flatten is no good: http://ideone.com/CvvBHe

Comment: Neither is toList: http://ideone.com/qgK3RU . Both don't include the uptree elements.

Comment: What would you want the result of `f (Tree 1 [Tree 2 []])` to be?

Comment: Well f ( Tree (Sum 1) [Tree (Sum 2) []] ) should be [1,3]

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the part about `a` being Monoid and just looked at `f`'s signature. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of abstractions, if you generalize the tree type to any *foldable container* (not just lists),
[`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:concatMap), [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid), [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) would apply:

```
import Prelude hiding (concatMap)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, concatMap)
import Data.Monoid (Monoid, mappend, mconcat)

data Tree a f = Tree a (f (Tree a f))

flatten :: (Monoid a, Foldable t) => Tree a t -> [a]
flatten (Tree r tr) = r: (mappend r <$> concatMap flatten tr)
```

then

```
\> let tr = Tree "a" [Tree "b" [], Tree "c" [Tree "d" []]]
\> flatten tr
["a","ab","ac","acd"]
```

Comment: Well of course you can do that, but you need to pattern match on the constructor at some point. I.e. flatten is specific to the Tree data type and is not expressible via folds and traverses alone. It's a new operation. Now the question is, can Tree/flatten be generalized into some *nice* type class?